# Combining both AND & OR with multiple conditions in mongodb filter query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to mongoDb and need to fetch the all records based on below condition, Need to combine all in single filter

**Condition**

1. (Status == NA) AND (Comments == "")
   OR
2. (Status == OPEN) AND (Comments == "")
   OR
3. Status == OPEN

Note: The condition to be applied to all checklist below (1, 2, 3 and so on) respectively

**Sample Data**

```
 {
        "ID": “1”,
        "Name": “Demo1”,
        "CheckList": {
            “CheckList1”: {
                "Status": "OPEN",
                “Comments”: ""
            },
            "CheckList2”: {
                "Status": "DONE",
                "Comments": “Completed”
            },
            "CheckList3”: {
                "Status": "NA",
                "Comments": ""
            },
            "CheckList4”: {
                "Status": "DONE",
                "Comments": “Completed”
            },
            "CheckList5”: {
                "Status": "NA",
                "Comments": “not applicable”
            },
        }
    },
```

Need filter with primitive type bson.D, I tried below but no records returned and i know there is a issue in this filter

```
filter := bson.D{
    {“CheckList.CheckList1.Comments”, ""},
    {“CheckList.CheckList2.Comments”, ""},
    {“CheckList.CheckList3.Comments”, ""},
    {“CheckList.CheckList4.Comments”, ""},
    {“CheckList.CheckList5.Comments”, ""},
    {"$or", bson.A{
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList1.Status", "NA"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList1.Status", "OPEN"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList2.Status", "NA"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList2.Status", "OPEN"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList3.Status", "NA"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList3.Status”, "OPEN"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList4.Status", "NA"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList4.Status", "OPEN"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList5.Status", "NA"}},
        bson.D{{"CheckList.CheckList5.Status", "OPEN"}},
    }}} 

Cursor, err := db.example.find(filter)
```

Please help!

Comment: It is ambiguous about the expected behaviour from your current information provided now. The condition should be applied to **all** entries of checklist or **any** entry?

Comment: it should be applied to all entries of checklist.. that's the complexity here

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd and 3rd conditions can be combined into the 3rd condition alone as they are OR conditions. Do an `$objectToArray` to convert your object into an array of k-v tuples, with v as the content of the `CheckList` objects. Then, use `$map` to apply the condition check and map to a boolean array. Lastly, use `$allElementsTrue` on the resulting array for final `$match`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "CheckList": {
        "$objectToArray": "$CheckList"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$allElementsTrue": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$CheckList.v",
            "as": "cl",
            "in": {
              "$or": [
                {
                  "$and": [
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "NA",
                        "$$cl.Status"
                      ]
                    },
                    {
                      "$eq": [
                        "",
                        "$$cl.Comments"
                      ]
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  "$eq": [
                    "OPEN",
                    "$$cl.Status"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "CheckList": {
        "$arrayToObject": "$CheckList"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zQblSJ_6XeW)

---

P.S. You should store the `CheckList` objects as an array instead of a single object like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Jm44wkYqC6S). You can then avoid complex aggregation that involves array-object conversions and gain a potential performance boost through indexing.

Comment: Thank you @ray!, i will try this and let you know